# Elegant way to create a new map from old one in Java, while keeping the sorting of elements the same

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, treemap, case-insensitive

Let's consider the following code:

```
//...

public Map<String, Integer> getFruits() throws SomeException {
    QueryResult[] queryResults = queryFruits();
    Map<String, Integer> fruits = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    for (QueryResult qr : queryResults) {
        fruits.put(qr.getField("Name").toString(), (Integer) rec.getField("ArticleNumber"));
    }
    return fruits;
}

//...

public static void main(String args[]) {
    App app = new App();
    Map<String, Integer> originalFruits = app.getFruits();
    System.out.println(originalFruits.keySet());
}
```

– the result of execution will be

```
[Apple, banana, cherry, Dragon_Fruit, Papaya ]
```

After that I'm calling `getApprovedFuits()` and passing `originalFruits` to it, along with `whiteListedFruitNames`:

```
public Map<String, Integer> getApprovedFruits(Map<String, Integer> fruits, Set<String> whiteListedFruitNames) {
    Map<String, Integer> approvedFruits = new TreeMap<>(fruits);
    approvedFruits.keySet().retainAll(whiteListedFruitNames);
    return approvedFruits;
}

//...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();
    Map<String, Integer> originalFruits = app.getFruits();

    // v

    Set<String> whiteListedFruitNames = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Apple",
                                                                    "banana",
                                                                    "cherry",
                                                                    "Dragon_Fruit",
                                                                    "kiwi",
                                                                    "Pineapple"));

    Map<String, Integer> approvedFruits = getApprovedFruits(originalFruits, whiteListedFruitNames);
    System.out.println(approvedFruits.keySet());

}
```

– the result of the latter `println()` will look like this:

```
[Apple, Dragon_Fruit, banana, cherry]
```

– and I expected to see this:

```
[Apple, banana, cherry, Dragon_Fruit]
```

And here is my question: how to make map constructor `TreeMap<>(fruits)` respect the sorting order of the map that is passed to it? Is there an elegant way to create a new map based on the original one, with the same sorting order?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#comparator()

Comment: I think you forgot your case-insensitive comparator when you declared your new TreeMap in getApprovedFruits

Comment: You can't put `String, String` into a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: @shmosel thanks! that was a typo...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TreeMap` has a [constructor from a `SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.SortedMap-) that retains the same `Comparator` (and thus, the ordering). However, since you're passing your `TreeMap` as a `Map`, this constructor is not used - instead, the [constructor from a `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Map-) is called, and the ordering is lost.

To make a long story short - change `getApprovedFruits`' signature to use a `SortedMap` and you should be fine:

```
public Map<String, Integer> getApprovedFruits
    (SortedMap<String, Integer> fruits, Set<String> whiteListedFruitNames) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Two other options in addition to @Mureinik's answer:

1. Construct your new `TreeMap` with an explicit comparator:

   ```
   Map<String, Integer> approvedFruits = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   approvedFruits.putAll(fruits);
   ```
2. If you're not planning on adding to the resulting map, you can use `LinkedHashMap` which will simply keep the initial insertion order:

   ```
   Map<String, Integer> approvedFruits = new LinkedHashMap<>(fruits);
   ```